# Error mapping data frame in R: is.data.frame(map) is not TRUE

Tags: r, mapping

I am trying to generate a map using the following data and code:

```
fileURL <- c("https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-jAX5hT2D3hNnVtLVhROENKRGs")
require(data.table)
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
ge.planted <- fread(fileURL, na.strings = "NA")
ge.planted[,-1]
colnames(ge.planted) <- c("region", "type", "crop", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
ge.planted.tidy <- ge.planted%>%
        gather(year, percent.planted, -c(region, type, crop))
ge.planted.tidy$region <- tolower(ge.planted.tidy$region)

require(ggplot2)
require(maps)
states <- map_data("state")
snames <- data.frame(region=tolower(state.name), long=state.center$x, lat=state.center$y)
ge.planted.m <- merge(snames, ge.planted.tidy, by="region", all=TRUE)
ge.planted.m$region <- as.character(ge.planted.m$region)
qplot(long, lat, data=ge.planted.m, geom="map", map = region, fill=percent.planted)
```

When I run this the following error is returned:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'region' not found
```

I initially thought that I was getting the error because region was a factor and not a character variable, but I have converted it to a character variable (second to last line of code) but the error remains the same with or without it.

Comment: In my case, `fread` throws the following error message: `Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch='h'`.

Comment: Please edit your post with example data, your code gives errors at `fread(...`. Also, at which stage do you get your error with `eval`, at `qplo`t?